# ::Create font return Invalid Handler X64 bit

Tags: c++11

I am using visual studio 2017 update 15.3.  i have compile the following code but get invalid font handle . return HFONT handle as 0xffffffff045875ca;

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "Windows.h"

int main()
{
    CFont font;
    LOGFONT lf;
    memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));       // zero out structure
    lf.lfHeight = 12;                      // request a 12-pixel-height font
    _tcsncpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE,
        _T("Arial"), 7);                    // request a face name "Arial"
    HFONT hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you thin `0xffffffff045875ca` is invalid? The documentationn states that `CreateFontIndirect()` returns `NULL` on error.

Comment: when i do operation on Cfont::FromHandle(...)  and select the font application crash so i thing that handler is invalid

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a `CFont` object from MFC, but are creating a font using the Windows API directly. Calling the global function `CreateFontIndirect` does not change the unrelated `CFont` instance `font`, instead you should use [`CFont::CreateFontIndirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3fad6bfe-d6ce-4ab9-967a-5ce0aa102800.aspx#cfont__createfontindirect):

```
CFont font;
LOGFONT lf;
memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));       // zero out structure
lf.lfHeight = 12;                      // request a 12-pixel-height font
_tcsncpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE,
    _T("Arial"), 7);                    // request a face name "Arial"
font.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
```